# how to create div fixed when resize?

Tags: html, css

i have two div, #red width 70% and #blue width 30%..

I want, when resizing. only the red div will shrink, blue div will not shrink at all. The reason that the letter was not crowded menu.

this my example 
[work](http://plnkr.co/edit/UsaphFdRzJTPO2y1GMbT?p=preview)

```
[1]plnkr.co/edit/UsaphFdRzJTPO2y1GMbT?p=preview
```

anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: add min-width to blue div

Comment: Thanks for reply,

it's doesn't work.. whether to use px than % ?

Comment: fixed width is always given in terms of px's.

Comment: this can be achieved using javascript

Comment: oh ya? do you want to create of sample with javascript ?

Comment: Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c6a66oge/3/

Comment: @Yameen Just in case your comment is misconstrued: min/max width is not just limited to `px`, any standard CSS *length* value can be used (px, cm, em, rem, % etc.).

Comment: Yes @asherstoppard Agree

Comment: hi all, can you help me for this case ? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893685/full-height-columns-on-bootstrap) , I have yet to get a relief. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two columns, one column you want to keep fixed width and for the other column you want to fill the remaining space and resize the width with the change in screen width.
Well there are many possible ways to achieve this.

I will show you a simple way to do it using the CSS Flex-box.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{
    display:flex;
    min-width:150px;
}
.red{
    background:red;    
    height:100px;   
    flex:1;
    min-width:50px;
}
.blue{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;   

}
```

Check it here on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c6a66oge/3/